# remove parentheses preserve float

Tags: python, string, list

I have a list of list of floats:

`l = [[1.1,1.1],[1.2,1.2]]`

To remove the square brackets - I ran:
`bb = [",".join([repr(s) for s in i]) for i in l]`

but `bb[0]` gives me a string `'1.1,1.1'`

UPDATE: A bit of context - it is my first time trying to process the data to input into a database, and it seems that the array output above does work given `{ }` parentheses.

Comment: It's not really clear what type of data you want. Two floats separated by a comma is a tuple. Do you want: `[tuple(i) for i in l]`? It might help to give us the value you want `bb` to be.

Comment: Hud, in your understanding what do the square brackets mean about your data? And given that, what are you trying to change? Because while `join()` will produce a result without a square bracket - that's because it's turning a number into a string.

Comment: Mark Nathaniel, thanks for the inputs. Apologies, but yes it would've been a tuple. However the string output above did work for my case (which I didn't elaborate)

Answer (score 0):

Are you trying to expand this list?

```
l = [[1.1,1.1],[1.2,1.2]]

print([num for item in l for num in item])

# [1.1, 1.1, 1.2, 1.2]
```